# ¿Cómo lanzar un Fragment heredado?

Tags: java, android

Buenos días.

Estoy intentando usar ButterKnife para mi proyecto y para no tener que hacer Bindings en cada uno de los Fragments que use, he decidido crear un BaseFragment con el unbinder para no repetirlo.

```
public abstract class BaseFragment extends Fragment {...}
```

Luego creo un Fragment mío propio que llamo ScheduleFragment y que hereda de BaseFragment

```
public class ScheduleFragment extends BaseFragment {...}
```

Pues bien, al intentarlo lanzar, creo todo, pero al usar el método .replace() se pide como parámetro lo que vayas a inflar, en éste caso R.id.fragment y el Fragment que vayas a lanzar como tal.

```
FragmentTransaction ft  = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ScheduleFragment sf     = new ScheduleFragment();
ft.replace(R.id.fragment, sf);
ft.commit();
```

Con Fragments "normales" que heredan de la clase Fragment no he tenido problemas, pero con un Fragment creado heredando BaseFragment, el constructor dice que como no es un Fragment si no un ScheduleFragment, que no es válido. ¿Alguien sabe en qué me equivoco?

Por supuesto que he intentado hacer un casting y me dice que no son compatibles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crea un objeto de tipo `Fragment` el cual lo inicialices con la instancia de tu fragmento `new ScheduleFragment();`. Recuerda que las importaciones de los fragmentos deben ser las misma, tanto la del fragmento que creas como la del objeto `Fragment`.

```
import android.app.Fragment;

public abstract class BaseFragment extends Fragment {...}
```

LLamas al fragmento

```
import android.app.Fragment;

...

FragmentTransaction ft  = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
Fragment sf     = new ScheduleFragment();
ft.replace(R.id.fragment, sf);
ft.commit();
```

Comment: David, mi problema estaba en las importaciones, en uno tenía Fragment y en el otro support.v4.app.Fragment. Ya había probado a crear el objeto tipo Fragment, pero me decía que no eran compatibles, claro. **Muchísimas gracias**